# How to get all database names and table names from sqlite

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite, cordova

I have planed to create a SQLite command editor for android application through cordova, app inside I will allow user to create unlimited table and database,so when they are enter into the application I need to select the database from popup menu then only I can execute the user's query. Also I need to get all the table name from specified database.
I have tried the following SQL query but no use.

```
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

Comment: Google *sqlite get tables*

Comment: @juergen I need to get existing all db names, I know to search in google but Im not found. So only I posted here.If you can help me donn't hurt me like this.

Comment: Every sqlite file can hold one DB. To combines files use ATTACH.

Comment: Databases are just files, and might be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
        arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

create a method in your DB class, this return all the table name

Comment: Where can I write this?

Comment: create a method in your DB class, this return all the table name

Comment: I found the whole example for getting table name, But I want to get all DataBase Names